# Search Host Controller Service stuck in Starting SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, sharepoint-search, farm-admin

I have tried to Stop it and again start using Powershell and through Central Admin. No luck in Powershell and by Central Admin I got Timeout Error with Correlation ID. When checking this in ULS log same error message for Timeout.

At the same time below is error **Details** from **Event Viewer**:

> Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: domain\AccountName  ImpersonationLevel: None' in database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'InstanceName'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_getObject', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.

Also the below error for SSA:

> Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running.

Comment: Is it normal SSA or Cloud SSA?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to grant the execute permission to the user (or a group that they a part of) for the stored procedure in question:

```
USE service\account; GRANT EXEC ON dbo.DATABASE TO PUBLIC
```

Comment: But as per my understanding you don't need to give any other permissions manually on any DB for Service Account for Service Application Set up apart from add it in Domain User

Answer (score 0):

You can give execute permission for “WSS_Content_Application_Pools” user in the relevant database stored procedure.

Open Microsoft SQL server managent studio, in the 'SharePoint_Config' database->Programmability ->Stored Procedures-> right click “dbo.proc_ getObject”-> Properties->Permissions. Select ‘WSS_Content_Application_Pools’ in the Users or roles section, and grant ‘Execute’ permission in the Explicit section.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your useful suggestion.
As per my knowledge those permission will automatically granted for the service account during the configuration. So is there any reason or any scenario where  we need to grant the permissions manually.